# Redirect to index method of any controller using anchor tag asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to redirect to index action method of Zone Controller, but I receive an error:

> The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed.

```
<a href="/Zones/"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-inbox"></span> Zones</a>
```

Comment: If you want to redirect to `Zone` use `Zone` , not `Zones` !

Comment: Post you relevant code. How does your routing looks like ?

Answer (score 0):

Routing cannot resolve that link

`<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Zones")"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-inbox"></span> Zones</a>`

Use [Url.Action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Action)